# changing state in reducer, then change page

Tags: redux, react-router

I am trying to change the state for my app using my reducer:

```
const initialState = [
  {
    id: 0,
    language: '',
    session: '',
    values: '',
    accessCode: '',
    age: 0,
    gender: '',
    ethnicity: '',
    drinkOften: '',
    drinkConcern: '',
  },
];

export default function UserDetails(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: action.value,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am dispatching an action with he field that needs updating, and the value.

```
export const addDetails = (value, field) => ({
    type: types.ADD_DETAILS,
    value,
    field,
});
```

In my component I am dispatching the action here:

```
const language = e.target.value;
this.props.actions.addDetails(language, 'language');
```

How can I redirect to another page once the state has been updated, using `react-router`

```
  this.context.router.transitionTo('/');
```

Comment: Side note: Do you realize that at the start your state is an array but after dispatching ADD_DETAILS it changes to object?